Disable "You can open bookmarks, reading mode, and more from the Chrome menu" in chrome automation
In current Chrome/Chromedriver version (127, but this started some versions before), when running tests with Selenium, a "tooltip" with the following text appears:

You can open bookmarks, reading mode, and more from the Chrome menu

I would like to disable it, maybe there is a chrome option to do so?

To disable that kind of messages you must disable the SidePanelPinning feature. I am using the selenium/standalone-chrome docker image as webdriver but it also should work for a local Chrome installation.

Import the Selenium Options class
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

Add the option "--disable-features=SidePanelPinning"
op = Options()
op.add_argument('--disable-features=SidePanelPinning')

Add the Options to the webdriver instance
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", options=op)


